# VBA Finding Unique Distinct Values based on Multiple Dynamic Criteria

Tags: excel, vba, distinct, distinct-values

It's not too easy to explain this but basically I have a data set that pulls through information to the dashboard.

I am looking to find the unique distinct amount of managers matched to 5 simultaneous criteria.

The data set looks like this:

[image]

The dashboard has an option to chose criteria to search this database with which looks like this [image]

My Question is - Say I search the entire database for jobs by a certain Principal (using the * wildcard for all other criteria). How do I then find out the distinct number of managers and consultants working on these jobs?

Sorry I couldn't attach the figures as figures rather than a photo - not sure how to do it.

Comment: `COUNTIFS` will give you the total number of each.  If you want unique values, you should look into using `Range.Filter` for unique values or look into `Collections`.  If you want specific help with your code, you will need to post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Something I've used to find a unique value from multiple criteria is to add a 'helper' cell with the criteria concatinated.  From above it may be =a2&b2&c2&d2 in an unused cell copied down

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to demonstrate how you could approuch this:

My sample data...

[image]

Formula in `J1`:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((A2:A10=I1),MATCH(F2:F10,F2:F10,0)),ROW(F2:F10)-ROW(F2)+1)>0))
```

Formula in `J2`:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((A2:A10=I1)*(B2:B10=I2),MATCH(F2:F10,F2:F10,0)),ROW(F2:F10)-ROW(F2)+1)>0))
```

Formula in `J3`:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((A2:A10=I1)*(B2:B10=I2)*(C2:C10=I3),MATCH(F2:F10,F2:F10,0)),ROW(F2:F10)-ROW(F2)+1)>0))
```

All these formula need to be entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Unfortunately `IF(..` doesn't support wildcards, so that's why I do it like this.

Append on this for the 4th and 5th criteria....